# Move element on page based on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 3 blocks on the page.

On the second block, I have 3 cases (maybe more), there is also a background line, and there is a circle in the middle of the case on this line

```css
.block1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(214deg, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0.00) 0%, #4F8EFF 10%, #F5E550 90%, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0.00) 100%) center / 3px calc(100% - 100px) no-repeat;
  
  .circle {
    position: relative;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 3px #4F8EFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(50% - 8px);
  }
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 200px 50px;
}

.block3 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="block1"></div>

<div class="block2">
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="circle"></div>
       </div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 3</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block3"></div>
```

Right now this circle is only for the first case, inside `<div class="col-2">`

Is it possible to make it so that, depending on the page scroll, this circle moves through all cases, and becomes empty `<div class="col-2">`, just like I drew. And it is important that the color of this circle is the same as the color of the line

That is, if we are in the middle of the page of the first case, then the circle should be on it, if we moved lower to the second case, then the circle should accordingly move to the second case, while I would like the circle itself to slide along with the scroll, and when scroll stop moved to the nearest case

[image]

Comment: Does the circle jump to the paragraphs or does it slide along the line?

Comment: @maraaaaaaaa I think it will be better if it jumps

Comment: @maraaaaaaaa although if it slides, but jumps to the nearest paragraph when scrolling stops, then it would probably be better

Comment: in that case place all the circles in the appropriate spots with the appropriate colors. Then hide all the ones except one depending on `$(window).scrollTop()`.

Comment: @maraaaaaaaa there is just a problem that the height of the block may increase or decrease depending on the screen size, and then the color of the circle may not match

Comment: If you do indeed want it to slide, then if you know your starting and ending colors of the gradient, you can calculate the color the circle needs to be in real time by finding the percentage the circle travelled across the line, and then use a `Lerp` algorithm with the two colors and the percentage value

Comment: You can use the lerp to dynamically color the circles also if the paragraphs can change in size

Comment: Otherwise, if you don't mind make the circle jump, just create all of them (with colors and stuff) and then hide them. At last, you can show the one who has the correct offset from the top...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved `.circle` out of `.case` so we only need to change its `top`.

`detectCase()` will find out which `.case` is closest to `.circle`

`handleScroll()` will change `.circle`'s top & `backgroundPosition` so its position and color will change while scroll.

```js
class ScrollCircle {
  constructor(container) {
    this.container = container;
    this.cases = this.container.querySelectorAll(".case");
    this.circle = this.container.querySelector(".circle");
    this.timer = null;
    this.lastScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    this.lastCircleTop = null;
    this.handleScroll();
    this.handleWindowSize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleWindowSize);
  }

  detectCase = () => {
    const circleCenter = this.circle.offsetTop + this.circle.offsetHeight / 2;
    let activeCase = null,
      minDist = Infinity;
    this.cases.forEach((elem) => {
      const caseTop = elem.offsetTop + elem.offsetHeight / 3;
      const dist = Math.abs(caseTop - circleCenter);
      if (dist < minDist) {
        minDist = dist;
        activeCase = elem;
      }
    });
    return activeCase;
  };

  scrollDown = () => {
    let down = window.scrollY > this.lastScrollPosition ? true : false;
    this.lastScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    return down;
  };

  handleScroll = () => {
    const maxTop = this.cases[this.cases.length - 1].offsetTop + this.cases[this.cases.length - 1].offsetHeight / 2;
    const minTop = this.cases[0].offsetHeight / 2;
    let {
      height: startTop
    } = this.cases[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    let circleTop = startTop / 2 + window.scrollY - this.container.offsetTop;
    circleTop = circleTop > maxTop ? maxTop : circleTop < minTop ? minTop : circleTop;
    let down = this.scrollDown();
    if ((circleTop < this.lastCircleTop && down) | (circleTop > this.lastCircleTop && !down)) {
      this.circle.style.top = `${this.lastCircleTop}px`;
      this.circle.style.backgroundPosition = `0 ${-this.lastCircleTop}px`;
    } else {
      this.circle.style.top = `${circleTop}px`;
      this.circle.style.backgroundPosition = `0 ${-circleTop}px`;
    }
    this.circle.style.backgroundSize = `15px ${this.container.offsetHeight}px`;
    if (this.timer) return;
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      const active = this.detectCase();
      circleTop = active.offsetTop + active.offsetHeight / 2;
      this.circle.style.top = `${circleTop}px`;
      this.circle.style.backgroundPosition = `0 ${-circleTop}px`;
      this.circle.style.transition = "0.5s";
      this.lastCircleTop = circleTop;
      this.timer = null;
    }, 800);
    this.circle.style.transition = null;
  };

  handleWindowSize = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 991) {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
      window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleScroll);
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
      window.removeEventListener("resize", this.handleScroll);
    }
  };
}

new ScrollCircle(document.querySelector(".block2"));
```

```css
.block1,
.block3 {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.block2,
.block2 .circle {
  background: linear-gradient(214deg, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0) 0%, #4f8eff 10%, #f5e550 90%, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0) 100%) center/3px calc(100% - 100px) no-repeat;
}

.block2 .circle {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
}

.block2 .circle,
.block2 .circle::before {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.block2 .circle::before {
  content: "";
  inset: 3px;
  background-color: white;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 200px 50px;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=so.css.map */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 3</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. But there is still such a question, how can I hide the scrolling functionality in the script for screens 991px and below? Because it's not enough to do this `<div class="circle d-lg-block"></div>`

Comment: I edited my ans. Add a new function `handleWindowSize()` to detect window size and add/remove the eventlistener.

Comment: Thanks, everything works fine, but there is another question, for example, if I increase block3 to 600px, for example, and scroll down, then the circle in the latter case will not stick, but will freeze and will not move anywhere. As far as I understand, this is because the scrollbar only works inside the case block. Is it possible to make it so that when scrolling a block with cases, the scrollbar stops and the circle sticks to the last case? And when they climbed back up to this block, it turned back on. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/t619wa3p/

Comment: Ans edited. The `.circle`'s top was not correctly calculated before. `let circleTop = startTop / 2 + window.scrollY;` should be `let circleTop = startTop / 2 + window.scrollY - this.container.offsetTop;`. I also update this part: "the scrollbar stops and the circle sticks to...", but I am not sure if I misunderstand.

Answer (score 0):

This should be more a comment then an answer... Here is how I would play with scroll, but color change is missing.

Oh! And you should give to `.col-2` some sort of ID to improve filtering on circle movement!

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  const offset = 0;
  let $circle = $('.circle');
  $('.case').each(function() {
    if(window.scrollY > ($(this).offset().top - offset)) {
      $(this).find('.col-2').append($circle);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.block1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(214deg, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0.00) 0%, #4F8EFF 10%, #F5E550 90%, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0.00) 100%) center / 3px calc(100% - 100px) no-repeat;
  
  .circle {
    position: relative;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 3px #4F8EFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(50% - 8px);
  }
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 200px 50px;
}

.block3 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="block1"></div>

<div class="block2">
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="circle"></div>
       </div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 3</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block3"></div>
```

Comment: There's something wierd on the circle positioning that I overseen before, but it could be related to the snippet tool itself...